# Punctuating lists with multiple sentences per item

Tags: semicolons

When each item of a list is composed of several long sentences, can you just separate them with a point?

I have the feeling sometimes the next connector (“second”, “then”, “next”) gets lost and the list is not easy to read anymore. Can I use a semi-colon (“;”) before “second”, “then”, “next” to separate the items clearly?

Example:

> Today I did many things: first, I went shopping with my sister. I bought a jean and a jacket. A special product for washing the jacket was offered to me for a cheap price. Second, I called Maria. Maria is always in a good mood although she was fired last month. She told me the next week she will travel to Paris. I think her friend Paula lives there. Next, I took the tram and went back home...

Comment: Altho' I've answered it below, this Q. would probably be better on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

First, that's not what I would call a *list*.  A *list* is usually a 'collection' of short names, items, etc. – not a sequence of events, nor a sequence of sentences.

Secondly, you *can* separate them just as you have done: there's nothing grammatically wrong with it, but it's not easy to read and is, perhaps, too broken up into too many short sentences.

Try this - it's less broken up and joins related things into single sentences, instead of lots of very short sentences. [The italics are just to highlight where I've made changes - not that you should use italics!]:

> Today I did many things.  *First,* I went shopping with my sister, *and bought* a *pair of jeans* and a jacket. *I also bought* a special product for washing the jacket, *which* was offered to me *cheaply*.
>
> *Next*, I called Maria, *who* is always in a good mood, *even though* she was fired last month. She told me *that* next week she will travel to Paris. I think her friend Paula lives there.
>
> Finally, I took the *tram back* home.

You've also asked whether you can use a *semi-colon ( ; )* before “second”, “then”, “next” to separate the items clearly? In some cases, separating items of a list with semi-colons may be appropriate.  But it is very definitely **not** appropriate in your case, because each individual item already contains two or more sentences.  If your individual items were much shorter, a semi-colon might be appropriate; but I wouldn't recommend using a semi-colon if your 'items' were much longer than here:

> Today I did many things.  First, I went shopping with my sister, and bought some clothes; then, I called Maria, who is always in a good mood, and is going to Paris next week; and finally, I took the tram home.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and very well developed answer.  I will try to use more connectors such as "and", "which"... However the example I used is not the one its causing me trouble. The one I'm working on has longer and more complicated sentences and because of this, I think that the solution of separating the sentences that you propose would be the appropriate.